# What is the reason for not shaving during Shravan Month?

Tags: shiva, fasting

In Hinduism there is month named "Shravan" which known as very holy month of Lord Shiva. Many People do fast during this month. Some people do fast only on every mondays and some does full month.

It is seen that some people who do fast are not shaving or cut their hair during whole month.

So what is the reason/story behind this ?

I have already read the question

- [Why do some Hindus observe fast during the month of “Shravan”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2045/467)
- [Why we don't eat non-veg, don't intake liquor and some people don't shave while Shravan Maas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2136/467), but none of this contain the answer for what I asked in the question.

Comment: It's been asked here - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2045/why-do-some-hindus-observe-fast-during-the-month-of-shravan?

Comment: @Sathya, Nopes, the shaving part is not discussed there, So this is totally a different question. Fasting is not my point in the question.

Comment: Also during Shravan, it is best time to carry out farming activities. And hence, barbers used to take leave and do farming for its own food requirements.

Answer (score 4):

**Religious reason for not Cutting & Shaving:**

It would stem from a tradition. There probably is no proof, but it probably stemmed from/is akin to being a nazareth. Most people have some type of tradition that they practice to honor traditions of old.

**Scientific reason for not Shaving:**

Shaving is not done in Shravan Maas because during that time, the Straight razor use to get infected by rust due to monsoon and it can cause skin injuries or you can say infections. Refer [straight razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_razor)

**Note:** There is no scientific reason for not cutting hair.